# Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil is erroring out saying I cant pass it a string

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-routes

I have been following this tutorial and I am [at this point](https://youtu.be/xVIV0LTchFs?t=768) and am receiving this error:

```
The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Route<Object?
```

I have built my routes within my main function in my main.dart file:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
      routes: {
        //define routes in this map
        '/login/': (context) => const LoginView(),
        '/register/': (context) => const RegisterView(),
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

And then in my login_view.dart file I try and use this route like this:

```
    TextButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushAndRemoveUntil('/register/', (route) => false);
      },
      child: const Text('Register'),
    )
```

The error I mentioned above is at the `'/register/'` which seems odd. I says it can not be a type string but in the tutorial he writes a string like this, and its this string that is in the map that defines the route... Not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used **pushAndRemoveUntil** which requires **Route<Object** but
as you are using Named routes u need to use **pushNamedAndRemoveUntil**

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/register/', (route) => false);
  },
  child: const Text('Register'),
)
```

Comment: thanks for the second eyes! Can't believe I missed that slight name difference!